# ContainerView nextViewController is not child stacked to container view as subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode-storyboard

I have 3 View Contorller

First View controller have Container View of height 300.0f at the center.

It has one embedded view Controller which is table View controller.
 On cell selection it should navigate to detailsViewController.

All the process is ok.

But detailsViewController is not behaving as embedded view controller of containerView and not of same size as container view.
It takes whole screen size.

As it is triggered from the embedded View Controller it should follow that frame without overlapping other controls which are in First View Controller.

Answer (score 1):

hope ganesh this will help you

Look You have a Container View  inside it you have a tableView  and By clicking an cell you pushing another viewController that what i concluded after reading your question(hope you done everything in modular way).

Now you must have UIView subclass(i.e separately creating a view class ) inside which you have a tableView so you pushing by

```
  [self.nav pushViewController:sos animated:YES];
```

there are two way to push ViewController inside a view first by Callback(through blocks) or passing Navigation ref. in UIView Class .So you are pushing the new Controller over the navigation thats why it showing this behavior and which is obvious.

Comment: Thanks Learner, Problem is solved by embedding the tableViewController in navigationController.

Comment: I have one question. The RootViewController that holds the containerView have a button. On that button press I hide and show the container View. The scenario is, I selected the cell and loaded the another view controller. Also I pressed the button on RootViewController which hides and shows the containerView. But next time when I press the button containerView Doesn't get reset. It still show another view controller instead of tableviewController. I just want to reset the container View with table View Controller. Please help me with this.

Comment: @Ganesh , yes it will show the detail view controller because you emmbedd it , i dont 100% sure but  look for your view's subview  [aView isKindOfClass:[YourClass class]] if it detailview type then alloc the table view type and if it already tableview then just show the view on button click.

Comment: @Ganesh problem solevd or not.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. But will definitely try and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed not view controller with table view, but embed navigationController(you can hide navigation panel on up side), end set yours table view controller as root for it, and use pushViewController to go to detail page.